# Making sure two threads one after another in a cycle - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two threads that start like this

```
    Thread player1Thread = new Thread(new Player1RunnableManual());
    player1Thread.start();
    Thread player2Thread = new Thread(new Player2RunnableManual());
    player2Thread.start();
```

The two players, player 1 and player 2 guess 100 numbers, one at a time, in different ways. We can ignore what heuristic they use to guess the number.
I need to make sure that player1 runs first, then player2 runs they player1 runs and then player2 again until one of them guesses a particular number(hardcoded).

I tried using a Reentrant lock, but I'm not able to make it work. The runnables for player1 and player2 are below.

How do I code a lock implementation to make it work?

```
class Player1RunnableManual implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!gopherFound) {
            r = new Random();
            final int player1Position = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
            final int outcome = calculateProximity(player1, player1Position);
            if (outcome != DISASTER) {
                runnableHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (holes[player1Position] == 0) {
                            setPosition(player1, player1Position);
                            player1Status.setText(outcomesList[outcome]);
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (outcome == SUCCESS) {
                    gopherFound = true;
                    winner = "Player 1";
                    result.setText("Player 1 wins");
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                int sleep = r.nextInt(threadHigh - threadLow) + threadLow;
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
}


class Player2RunnableManual implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100 && !gopherFound; i++) {
            final int player2Position = i;
            final int outcome = calculateProximity(player2, player2Position);
            if (outcome != DISASTER) {
                Message msg = messageHandler.obtainMessage(player2);
                msg.arg1 = player2Position;
                msg.arg2 = outcome;
                messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                if (outcome == SUCCESS) {
                    gopherFound = true;
                    winner = "Player 2";
                    result.setText("Player 2 wins");
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                int sleep = r.nextInt(threadHigh - threadLow) + threadLow;
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a single thread executor? The runnables will be enqueued.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
while(!gopherFound){
    executor.execute(new Player1RunnableManual());
    executor.execute(new Player2RunnableManual());
    // wait here for the end of the 2 runnables, maybe using Future tasks instead of runnables
}
```

you can clean the code, the runnables must not have anymore a "while (!gopherFound)" inside, but with this, you are sure the runnables are executed one after the other

An alternative is using a "Semaphore(1)", will do the job also using the "acquire()" and "release()" methods, but it can not warranty which thread will be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

For your `player1Thread` to start executing before `player2Thread` you need to call `join` on `player1Thread` before starting `player2Thread`. But this would mean that `player2Thread` will not start unless `player2Thread` dies.
A workaround for this is if you have an idea about how long after does `player1Thread` starts, should `player2Thread` start then pass that duration (converted to millis) as an argument to the `join` on `player1Thread`

OR

Use a single thread `Executor` and submit `Player1RunnableManual` and `Player2RunnableManual` in sequence. Also, don't forget to shutdown the `Executor`

About your approach using a `Reentrant Lock`. `Reentrent Lock` is the object-orient equivalent of using a `synchronized` block. You can do some practice exercises by converting one to another. It only performs synchronizations, it does not guarantee thread execution ordering. Access to shared object will be decided by the thread scheduler and it's kinda random.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure one action will fire after another. You can use simply `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Like next.

```
final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = 
  (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

executor.submit(new Runnable() {
     @Override 
     public void run() { 
           // Your action 1
     }
});

executor.submit(new Runnable() {
     @Override 
     public void run() { 
           // Your action 2
     }
})
```